# Limited company receiving GDPR data breach fine

Tags: company, gdpr, bankruptcy

Hypothetically speaking, if a European limited company's website is breached and a GDPR fine of 20m$ is fined towards the company. Can the company decide to declare bankruptcy and set-up-shop again under a new name and resolving the issue that caused the data breach in the previous company? Or is the fine an inevitable lifelong debt for small businesses?

Comment: Note that the fines are supposed to be "effective, proportionate and dissuasive". Driving a company into bankruptcy might effectively dissuade them from further offences, but would in most cases not be considered proportionate, so this scenario is quite hypothetical indeed.

Answer (score 5):

A limited company is exactly that: limited in liability. It can declare bankruptcy anytime and that´s it for the owners. Provided the CEO did not engage in gross misconduct, in which case he may be held accountable with his personal wealth.

But... declaring bankruptcy (or insolvency as it is called) does not automatically end a company. Instead it is given into the hands of a publicly appointed administrator who will see if anything can be salvaged.

It is then either sold to the highest bidder or dissolved and all the valuables sold off. 
Fees for the administrator are paid by this, then all the liabilities are paid off, if possible and, if there are any leftovers, the owners get the rest.

So it may well be continued under new rule or loos a lot more money than just paying the fine.

Also setting up shop elsewhere would require you do do all the investments again like building the website that breached the GDPR.

Also this example would probably never happen in real life, as fines are usually set in a way that is proportional to size of the offending the business. The goal of the  fine is not to kill the business, but to make it unattractive to offend again. Google will pay more than your butcher next door, for the same misconduct.

Comment: I think you might be missing a "not" at the beginning of your second paragraph ("does _not_ automatically end...").

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks, you are right. I corrected it.

Comment: @Daniel thank you very much, I was unaware that the fines are proportioned according to the size of the company. I always assumed it was a minimum of 20m$.

Comment: @KristianPospis The **maximum fine** under the GDPR is up to 4% of annual global turnover or €20 million – whichever is greater. The 4% turnover figure  gives you a glimpse of what proportions the the lawmakers had in mind.